# Can you use java.sql Types as column type in liquibase 1.9.5?

Tags: liquibase

Can you use java.sql Types as column type in liquibase 1.9.5 like in the latest version? Or do I need to resort to database specific types?

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, Liquibase 1.9.5 was released in October 2009.

I scanned the [jira release notes](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:versions-panel) and I don't see anything in the 2.0 releases that would indicate that support for the java.sql types is anything new.